# Trying to install Mezzanine via Docker

Tags: docker, mezzanine, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to install Mezzanine on Docker to test out Docker

I've used this [Container](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/noisy/mezzanine-docker-demo/) with [this postgres db](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/sameersbn/postgresql/), with a few customizations (namely commenting out) on the Mezzanine container and using the start.sh script to include DB info.

When I run these 2 Docker commands:

```
docker run -P --name some_web -p 80:80 --link some_db:db myapp/mezzanine-docker
    db: docker run -d --name="some_db" -e 'PSQL_TRUST_LOCALNET=true' myapp/docker-postgresql:latest
```

It throws this error:
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Why? Just need a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Is the order of commands correct in your question? You should create the database container *before* the application container when you intent to link `some_db` into `some_web`.

Comment: No, I didn't notice that they got flipped. I run the db command first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @helmbert because sometimes I encounter weird behavior of `docker-compose`. For me it seems like `docker-compose` can't guarantee the containers run order. So if `mezzanine` starts before the database initialization, it will obviously fail.

But the nature of the error that you describe suggests that your `django`-based application is improperly configured. Check the value of `DATABASES['default']['HOST']` in `settings.py`, it must be equal to `db`.

Comment: "HOST" is set to 127.0.0.1, everything I've read recommend that setting. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's OK only in case if you do it on your development workstation: when both webserver and database are working on the same host - your machine. But you're trying to create a distributed web application. So you have two different virtual machines - docker containers. They should interact as a real hosts and call each other by hostname. So you have two options here: either overwrite `DATABASES['default']['HOST']` (and make it equal to `db`), either expose PostgreSQL port on host (`docker run -d -p 5432:5432  (...)`).

Comment: Ah ok, I think the light bulb went on in my head :). So then this command, docker run -P --name some_web -p 80:80 --link some_db:db myapp/mezzanine-docker, should really .... -p 5432:5432 .... ?

Comment: Did you try to fix `DATABASES['default']['HOST']` field? `127.0.0.1` value is an obvious mistake.

In case if you for a some reason don't want to fix this error, you can map `postgres` container port to your host port (it should be considered as a bad design if `postgres` client are working only on the same host): 
1. `docker run -d --name="some_db" -p 5432:5432 -e 'PSQL_TRUST_LOCALNET=true' myapp/docker-postgresql:latest`
2. `docker run --name some_web -p 80:80 --link some_db:db myapp/mezzanine-docker`

Comment: Yes, I fixed the HOST setting, just need to test it. I'll post the result here

Comment: I re-ran the commands with the new port and still get the same error. Should I also state 5432 in the PORT in settings.py?

Comment: I think I may have found the issue, in the postgresql.conf file - #listen_addresses = 'localhost'   - that needs to get changed to #listen_addresses = '*'  doesn't it?